# Javascript inner.HTML not usable with a function - create moveable divs

Tags: javascript, dom, html, drag-and-drop

I want to take a list of users from a database, show their name in a table and when you click on a name, a special div apeears with his details, you can move this div and even close it.

Here is a short scheme how the code is written:

> 

function openDiv(id){
document.getElementById('divsHere').innerHTML +='<`div id="moveable'+id+'">`content`</div>`'}

```
 <?php database connection... while{
```

...

```
<tr onclick='openDiv( ". $row['id'] ." )'>
$script += 'Drag.init(document.getElementById("moveable'+ $row['id'] +'"));'
```

...

}?>

```
<div id="divsHere"></div>
```

echo $script;

I've used this awesome drag'n'drop library. 
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex11/domdrag/index.htm
(note I have the same problems with jQuery)

It seems the drag'n'drop function doesn't work, when the div was addad by inner.HTML. However, I don't see any onther way around.

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is when you execute Drag.init the div you feed it is not yet created.

I sugest you generate the individual divs inside a php cycle, just like you do for the th tags, remove the setting of the innerHTML you have at the beginning of openDiv, and it'll work.

I have to say though, it seems like what you want is a modal dialog which you can find already made and easy to use elsewhere. For example: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/ It'll both be easier to work with and your likely to enjoy the final result more.

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the div using `document.createElement`:

```
var newDiv = document.createElement('div'), 
    textNode = document.createTextNode('content');
newDiv.id = "moveable" + id;
newDiv.appendChild(textNode);
document.getElementById('divsHere').appendChild(newDiv);
```

and to initialise the dragging simply do

```
Drag.init(newDiv);
```

provided that part of the code where you want to initialise the dragging has `newDiv` within its scope.

(Probably you want to create the `div` and initialise the possibility of dragging it in the same place. If I've understood your scheme right, then the problem is that it first tries to initialise dragging on non-existent divs, then only when the user clicks on a row, calling the function `openDiv`, are those divs created. If this is right then to fix it, you need to make sure the dragging is only initialised *after* the div has been created.)